# Is there a word for centering the English language that is disconnected from England?

Tags: american-english, british-english, business-language

I am looking to describe the centering of the English language (in a US-based but global business culture). The company itself is based in California, and what I'm seeing is an intersection of US-centrism with eurocentrism, specifically Anglocentrism. But while "Anglocentrism" means "practice of viewing the world from English or Anglo-American perspective, with an implied belief, either consciously or subconsciously, in the preeminence of English or Anglo-American culture," it is referring to English as in England, not English as in the language English, wherever it is spoken (e.g. California).

TLDR: Is there a word to denote "practice of viewing the world from an English-speaking perspective, with an implied belief, either consciously or subconsciously, in the preeminence of the English language?"

Comment: For anybody to even begin to think about answering this question, it needs to be explained what is meant by 'centering the English language', and whether the question is really about centering the language (as the title and the first sentence seem to indicate), or on centering one's worldview on the language (which is what the rest of the question seems to be about).

Comment: Which company are you referring to, and how is the corporation related to anglocentrism?

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't very clear, but what you may be describing is an **Anglophone worldview.**

> Anglophone: English speaking ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/anglophone))

> worldview: A particular philosophy of life or conception of the world. ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/world_view))